# how to reduce all fields by 50% using cursors [transact SQL]

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

So what I'm trying to do is to reduce all the values of MSRP by 50%. I wrote this stored procedure, but instead reducing it increases the values by aloot so that it reaches the int limit and gives my an error.
Could you please help me find the error?

```
Create PROCEDURE MSRP_raise10 as

DECLARE @MSRP as int 
DECLARE kursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT MSRP from products 
OPEN kursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor
INTO @MSRP
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
UPDATE products SET
    MSRP = @MSRP * 0.5
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor into @MSRP
END
CLOSE kursor
DEALLOCATE kursor
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you doing a cursor for this?, you should simply use

```
UPDATE products 
SET MSRP = MSRP * 0.5
```

Ok, now, to try to answer your question, I don't know why you are receiving the error, but the logic in your cursor is flawed. You are basically storing the value of every `MSRP` in the table into the `@MSRP` variable and then updating **the whole table** so every row has the same value for `MSRP`, which will be `@MSRP * 0.5`, and you are doing that same update for every initial value of `MSRP` that your table had.

Comment: I used the cursor because I wanted to learn how to use it, turns out I misunderstood the concept, thanks alot for explaining

Comment: @KTW: Cursors can easily be abused because there really are few areas where cursors are either unavoidable or efficient enough to compete with set-based solutions. And while knowing how to use them would certainly not harm you, *not* knowing that might, to a degree, be an advantage, even if only at first, because that might make you push harder for looking for set-based alternatives.